# Compilation error when overloading a previously defined within a namespace function template

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, overload-resolution, argument-dependent-lookup

**Is it a MinGW bug or an expected behavior?**

1. This version compiles:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr auto get_foo(T &t)
{
    return t.foo();
}

template<typename Impl>
class dummy
{
public:
    dummy() { [[maybe_unused]] auto &&foo = get_foo(impl_); }

private:
    Impl impl_;
};

struct Foo{};
using TupleFoo = std::tuple<Foo>;

Foo &get_foo(TupleFoo &tuple) { return std::get<Foo>(tuple); }

int main(int, char **)
{
    TupleFoo tuple{};
    [[maybe_unused]] auto &&foo = get_foo(tuple);
    [[maybe_unused]] auto d = dummy<TupleFoo>();

    return 0;
}
```

2. This version will not compile when instantiating `dummy`:

```
namespace custom
{
    template<typename T>
    constexpr auto get_foo(T &t)
    {
        return t.foo();
    }

    template<typename Impl>
    class dummy
    {
    public:
        dummy() { [[maybe_unused]] auto &&foo = get_foo(impl_); }

    private:
        Impl impl_;
    };
}

struct Foo
{
};
using TupleFoo = std::tuple<Foo>;

namespace custom
{
    Foo &get_foo(TupleFoo &tuple) { return std::get<Foo>(tuple); }
}


int main(int, char **)
{
    TupleFoo tuple{};
    [[maybe_unused]] auto &&foo = custom::get_foo(tuple);
//    [[maybe_unused]] auto d = custom::dummy<TupleFoo>(); // will not compile

    return 0;
}
```

3. This version will compile:

```
// Type and function definitions come before templates 
struct Foo
{
};
using TupleFoo = std::tuple<Foo>;

namespace custom
{
    Foo &get_foo(TupleFoo &tuple) { return std::get<Foo>(tuple); }
}

namespace custom
{
    template<typename T>
    constexpr auto get_foo(T &t)
    {
        return t.foo();
    }

    template<typename Impl>
    class dummy
    {
    public:
        dummy() { [[maybe_unused]] auto &&foo = get_foo(impl_); }

    private:
        Impl impl_;
    };
}

int main(int, char **)
{
    TupleFoo tuple{};
    [[maybe_unused]] auto &&foo = custom::get_foo(tuple);
    [[maybe_unused]] auto d = custom::dummy<TupleFoo>(); // will not compile

    return 0;
}
```

I would understand if version 3 would work, but 1 and 2 would not compile regardless of using a namespace. But 1 and 2 behave differently.

Practically using 3 is inconvenient since one would have to include header with templates after function declaration. That could lead to very ambiguous errors.

Error:

```
In instantiation of 'constexpr auto custom::get_foo(T&) [with T = std::tuple<Foo>]':
../Modules/eos/sandbox/sb_eos_algorithm.cpp:72:56:   required from 'custom::dummy<Impl>::dummy() [with Impl = std::tuple<Foo>]'
../Modules/eos/sandbox/sb_eos_algorithm.cpp:93:55:   required from here
../Modules/eos/sandbox/sb_eos_algorithm.cpp:65:18: error: 'class std::tuple<Foo>' has no member named 'foo'; did you mean 'struct Foo Foo::Foo'? (not accessible from this context)
   65 |         return t.foo();
```

Comment: ADL uses namespace of function's arguments, so, for `std::tuple<Foo>`, in `std` and global namespace, but `get_foo(TupleFoo &)` is in namespace `custom`.

Comment: Good place for `get_foo(TupleFoo&)` is in same namespace than `Foo`.

Comment: @Jarod42 can you clarify? Why does it compile for `auto &&foo = custom::get_foo(tuple)` in main then?

Comment: BTW, unclear what is your question?

Comment: @Jarod42 the question is generally about "how do I make this work"

Comment: `custom::get_foo` is qualified lookup, so no ADL, `get_foo(impl_)` is unqualified lookup, so use ADL.

Comment: *"how do I make this work"*, As you show, you have version1 and version3 which compile.

Comment: @Jarod42 even if I add `using namespace custom` and call `get_foo(impl_)` directly within the class `custom::dummy`, I still get the same error. Number one is unacceptable because there is no namespace, number 3 is very error prone.

Comment: Two-phase name lookup. The name `get_foo` used in `dummy` is first looked up at the point of definition, using ordinary lookup; this finds the first (generic) overload only, since `get_foo(TupleFoo&)` overload is not declared yet. Then at the point of instantiation, the name `get_foo` is looked up again - but only by argument-dependent lookup. This doesn't find the second overload as none of the arguments are associated with `custom` namespace. So the first overload is chosen.

Comment: As I said, place `get_foo(TupleFoo&)` in same namespace than `Foo`.

Comment: @Jarod42 I placed `Foo &get_foo(TupleFoo&` in the same namespace with `Foo` (that is, global). Still the same error in `dummy`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik so, it is an expected behavior then. Is version 3 the only possible solution, or something else could be done (to make usage less error prone)? I'll accept it as an answer.

Comment: Works as expected [here](https://godbolt.org/z/oEa3zE8Tr) (Notice that `custom::get_foo` is now wrong as not using ADL).

Comment: The call in `dummy` [works for me](https://godbolt.org/z/bzTP9Pxob) once the second `get_foo` overload is moved to global namespace, next to `Foo`. The call `custom::dummy<TupleFoo>()` doesn't of course, but that's to be expected (as this can only possibly use the generic overload in `custom` namespace).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik noice! But `auto &&foo = custom::get_foo(tuple)` now fails :).

Comment: Well, if you want that to work, then `get_foo` must be in `custom` namespace. If `Foo` can't also be in `custom` namespace, then you can't rely on ADL and must declare the overload in such a way that it's visible to `dummy` definition.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I like this solution (@Jarod42 basically has the same). It is better than including a header after defining types and function "overloads"