# Partial class template specialization based on a condition?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I generally don't see, how it could be implemented.

I have an incomplete class template used to "override" some methods.
This one is a working example:

```
template<typename...>
struct make_completion;

struct ServiceTraits
{
    using mode_type = ModeType;
    using warning_type = Waring;
    using error_type = Error;
    using iteration_result_type = IterationResult;

    using steering_type = Steering;

    using sync_tag_t = decltype(asio::use_future);
};

template<typename SignatureT>
struct make_completion<ServiceTraits, SignatureT>
{
    template<typename CompletionToken>
    auto operator()(ServiceTraits, CompletionToken &&completionToken)
    {
        using result_type = asio::async_result<std::decay_t<CompletionToken>, SignatureT>;
        using completion_handler = typename result_type::completion_handler_type;

        completion_handler handler{ std::forward<CompletionToken>(completionToken) };
        result_type result{ handler };

        return Completion<result_type, completion_handler>{ std::move(result), std::move(handler) };
    }
};
```

I want to assemble `traits` class via inheritance, so, for instance, I would have several traits classes and then arbitrarily combine them.

For example:

```
template<typename ResultT, typename HandlerT>
struct completion
{
   using result_type = ResultT;
   using handler_type = HandlerT;
   result_type result;
   handler_type handler;
};

// this would be inherited from
struct asio_traits
{
   using sync_tag_t = decltype(asio::use_future);
};
```

The problem is, I can not use something like `std::enable_if` in a specialization.
This will not compile:

```
template<typename DerivedTraits,
         typename SignatureT,
         typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<asio_traits, DerivedTraits>>>
struct eos::method::make_completion<DerivedTraits, SignatureT>
{
   // impl here...
};
```

Is it possible to somehow use a condition for class template specialization?

Comment: You typically use a dummy type template argument in the primary template, `template<typename Enable = void>` and in restricted partial specializations you would pass the result of `std::enable_if_t` as template argument: `struct eos::method::make_completion<std::enable_if_t< ... >> ...`. A template parameter pack cannot be followed by an additional template parameter, however, so this adds some complexion. I would suggest using mixings for the combined trait, and provide this a single type template parameter to the `make_completion` class template.

Comment: @dfrib thank you for your suggestions. If you can show an example, I would consider it as a legit answer. For now I just separated `asio_traits` as an `async_traits` dependent typename. It it simple enough

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
template <typename...>
struct make_completion_tag;

template <typename Tag, typename...>
struct make_completion_impl;

template <typename... Ts>
struct make_completion : public make_completion_impl<
    typename make_completion_tag<Ts...>::type,
    Ts...>
{};

struct asio_traits_based_tag;
template <typename DerivedTraits, typename SignatureT>
struct make_completion_impl<asio_traits_based_tag, DerivedTraits, SignatureT> {
  // Your specialization here
};
```

Now it's just a matter of getting `make_completion_tag::type` to return the correct tag. E.g.

```
template <typename DerivedTraits, typename SignatureT>
struct make_completion_tag<DerivedTraits, SignatureT> {
  using type = std::conditional_t<
      std::is_base_of_v<asio_traits, DerivedTraits>,
      asio_traits_based_tag, void>;
};
```

---

EDIT: a slightly different approach that exposes an external customization point:

```
template <typename Tag, typename...>
struct make_completion_impl;

void make_completion_selector(...);

template <typename... Ts>
struct make_completion : public make_completion_impl<
    decltype(make_completion_selector(static_cast<Ts*>(nullptr)...)),
    Ts...>
{};
```

Now the user has two options. If the types allow, they could specialize `make_completion` directly:

```
template <AnotherType>
struct make_completion<SpecificType, AnotherType> {
  // Your specialization here
};
```

In a more complicated case, they can declare a suitably constrained overload of `make_completion_selector` returning a tag type, and specialize `make_completion_impl` on that tag:

```
struct asio_traits_based_tag;
template <typename DerivedTraits, typename SignatureT>
struct make_completion_impl<asio_traits_based_tag, DerivedTraits, SignatureT> {
  // Your specialization here
};

template <typename DerivedTraits, typename SignatureT>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<asio_traits, DerivedTraits>,
                 asio_traits_based_tag>
make_completion_selector(DerivedTraits*, SignatureT*);
```

Comment: There is nothing *special* about `make_completion_tag<DerivedTraits, SignatureT>`  specialization since `DerivedTraits` and `SignatureT` are as generic as they were. So while you did make it work for `asio_traits`, you made it fail for all the other specializations. Compiler will fail to deduce between `asio_traits` and `some_other_traits` "specializations", if one would want to add them. The only thing that distinguishes between `make_completion_tag` specializations is a number of template arguments. Which is always 2 in my case. Thanks for the effort though.

Comment: If you need more tags, you could put more clauses into `std::conditional`. Or you could have a bunch of overloaded helper functions returning a tag, selected via SFINAE, and make it `using type=decltype(tag_helper((DerivedTraits*)nullptr, (SignatureT*)nullptr));`

Comment: Why would I want that? The whole point of this approach is to have specializations which are agnostic of each other, and the base template does not need to know anything about specializations. By adding tags to `std::conditional` this intention will be broken, since you will have to bring all the possible tags together, introducing dependencies on their headers. The goal here is convenience for the user: one would need to write only one specialization without ever changing the implementation.

Comment: Could you ask the user to declare an overload of a particular function name, constrained with SFINAE? E.g. `struct my_tag; template <typename D, typename S> std::enable_if_t<some_condition, my_tag> make_completion_selector(D*, S*);` Then you could use `decltype(make_completion_selector((Ts*)nullptr ...)` as a tag to select `make_completion_impl<my_tag, ...>` specialization.

Comment: The point of this question is the fact that I can't use SFINAE when specializing a class template. SFINAE assumes a condition in the general template. So if I put an assumption that a particular traits class must be a base of a template parameter, one would be forced to use inheritance. This is rather convoluted and seems to me very hard to maintain. Now I am using a simpler solution - nested typedefs. The approach with SFINAE would require to define a `Type` in a basic template and implicitly check if it is a base of another `Type` or the same by default... You could try this

Comment: You can't use SFINAE when specializing a class template, but you can use SFINAE when overloading a function template. The trick I suggest replaces the former with the latter. While perhaps not perfect, would it be good enough?

Comment: Overloading a function template will not work as expected due to ADL - one will be forced not to use a namespace when invoking such a function. And this might cause nasty errors. You can modify your answer with an example, maybe I miss something. But the reason I am using class template specialization is the inability to partially specialize a template function in C++.

Comment: Edited the answer with an example. I'm not sure I quite get the ADL point. Customizing `make_completion_selector` is little different than customizing [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Swappable)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68546667/compilation-error-when-overloading-a-previously-defined-within-a-namespace-funct you can look into this question to try to get a closer look into the problem. I was looking for a way to customize ("override") a default function with templates. I stopped with using a specialization for callable class template (it works as expected). But it also has its own limits...